# Why is no message received in WS communication on a UWP device?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket, uwp, hololens

I have a WS server and I would like to broadcast messages from that server (using another web app) to all HoloLens devices that are connected to the session.

First I have implemented a `MessageWebSocket` client in the Hololens app that initiated a connection with a sample public WS server `echo.websocket.org` just to check if the setup is right on the client side. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

#if WINDOWS_UWP
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Web;
using System;

#endif

public class WebSocketClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

#if WINDOWS_UWP
            int msgTime = 5;
            int fadeTime = 1;
            guiPhraseReporter.QueueRaport("START", msgTime, fadeTime);
            MessageWebSocket ws = new MessageWebSocket();
            ws.Control.MessageType = SocketMessageType.Utf8;
            ws.MessageReceived += (MessageWebSocket sender, MessageWebSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args) =>
            {
                guiPhraseReporter.QueueRaport("Trying to receive message...", msgTime, fadeTime);
                try
                {
                    using (DataReader dataReader = args.GetDataReader())
                    {
                        dataReader.UnicodeEncoding = UnicodeEncoding.Utf8;
                        string message = dataReader.ReadString(dataReader.UnconsumedBufferLength);
                        Debug.Log(message);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Error occurred");
                }
            };

            ws.Closed += (IWebSocket sender, WebSocketClosedEventArgs  args) => {
                Debug.Log("WS closed");
            };

            try
            {
                Task connectTask = ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri("ws://echo.websocket.org")).AsTask();
                connectTask.ContinueWith(async _ =>
                {
                    string message = "Hello, World!";
                    using (DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(ws.OutputStream))
                    {
                        dataWriter.WriteString(message);
                        await dataWriter.StoreAsync();
                        dataWriter.DetachStream();
                    }
                    Debug.Log("Sending Hello World");
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WebErrorStatus webErrorStatus = WebSocketError.GetStatus(ex.GetBaseException().HResult);
                // Add additional code here to handle exceptions.
                Debug.Log(ex);
            }

#endif

    }
}
```

And it works fine, I'm able to send a message to the server, and it is echoed back and received correctly by the client.

Things however mess up when I use the actual server I'll be testing on. On my server, I have replicated the behavior from the `echo.websocket.org` and I echo back any message sent. I'm able to connect, the connection is not closed (Closed is never called), but I don't receive any messages.

If I test both servers using the web browser (with chrome's Smart Websocket Extension), they both work. The only difference (and only possible lead I got) is that the sample server (the one that works on Hololens) sends more headers upon connection:

[image]

vs my server:

[image]

Maybe there is some easier way to do this, but so far I didn't find any good WS wrappers that would work on UWP. Any help appreciated.

Comment: is it possible that it is something about threads? Did you try to set Brakepoints and debug the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was faulty logic on my server app after all. So there was no problem with WS communication to begin with, thank you for your time.